# reconstructing a curve from its stroke

Tags: graphics

I am trying to reconstruct curves from (PDF) graphics. These consist of the outline of the curve ("stroke"). A typical example (monotonic in X, Y increasing over the hump and then dropping) is shown. The original stroke-width appears to be about 1.0, but this is of secondary interest.

[image: stroke outline]

I include the SVG representation below. At present my rather crude attempt would be to floodfill the curve and attempt to thin until I got a midline. However this seems fragile. Is there a better algorithm given that we have the analytical outline (as lines and cubic beziers?)

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
  <g transform="scale(25., 25.)">
    <g transform="translate(-110., -235.)">
      <path fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width=".05" 
        d="M114.06 242.46 L114.12 242.28 L114.18 242.16 L114.3 242.04 C114.36 241.98 114.36 241.92 114.42 241.92 
L114.48 241.86 C114.54 241.8 114.66 241.74 114.72 241.74 L114.78 241.74 C114.9 241.68 115.02 241.68 115.08 241.74 
L115.2 241.8 C115.26 241.8 115.32 241.8 115.38 241.86 L115.44 241.92 L115.5 241.92 L115.2 241.86 L115.38 241.86 
C115.44 241.86 115.5 241.86 115.56 241.86 L115.62 241.92 C115.74 241.92 115.8 241.92 115.86 241.98 L115.92 242.04 
C115.98 242.04 116.04 242.1 116.1 242.22 L116.16 242.22 C116.16 242.28 116.16 242.34 116.22 242.4 L116.28 242.52 
L116.34 242.7 L116.34 242.94 L116.4 243.18 L116.52 243.66 C116.58 244.02 116.34 244.32 116.04 244.44 
C115.68 244.5 115.32 244.26 115.26 243.9 L115.2 243.48 L115.14 243.24 L115.08 243.06 L115.08 242.94 
L115.02 242.82 L115.08 242.94 L115.02 242.88 L115.2 243.06 L115.14 243.0 L115.38 243.12 L115.26 243.12 
L115.5 243.12 L115.2 243.12 C115.08 243.12 115.02 243.12 114.9 243.06 L114.78 242.94 L114.66 242.88 
L114.84 243.0 L114.72 242.94 L115.08 242.94 L115.02 242.94 L115.26 242.88 L115.2 242.88 L115.32 242.76 
L115.32 242.82 L115.2 243.0 C115.08 243.3 114.72 243.42 114.36 243.3 C114.06 243.18 113.94 242.82 114.06 242.46 Z
      "/>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Answering own question since no comments or answers]

My best guess is that this curve was "drawn" with an "italic" pen which is always normal to the direction of the fundamental curve. Here's the roundedcaps version from inkscape

[image: rounded caps on lines]

My strategy is now:

1. to find two Curve segments which change the direction by 180 (I have code to do this)
2. calculate the diameter and use it as the stroke width of the original curve
3. start from one semicircle and extend along both lines leading off
4. interpret lines as (i) rectangle (ii) arc-left (iii) arc-right or (iv) arcs on both lines (trickier)
5. repeat until all components are analysed

I don't know whether it will work but I'm reasonably confident. I shall write this on a plane journey for fun.